# Query Always Hits the Network

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client

This query hits the network every time:

```
const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(GetCartByTokenDocument, {
  variables: { token: 'one' }
});
```

The cache explorer after the first call:

```
getCartByTokenQuery({token: 'one'}):
  __ref: "Cart:{}"
```

But it keeps hitting the network on all subsequent calls.

The only thing related in the cache config is:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Cart: {
      keyFields: [] // singleton
    }
  }
});
```

What can cause this? What am I doing wrong?

@apollo/client v3.7.7

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In the update function after a mutation I was modifying the cache like this:

```
cache.modify({
  fields: {
    getCartByToken() {
      return cart;
    }
  }
});
```

Wrong. You gotta convert the value to a reference:

```
cache.modify({
  fields: {
    getCartByToken(_, { toReference }) {
      return toReference(cart);
    }
  }
});
```

Similarly, I needed to convert new bookings to a reference:

```
cache.modify({
  id: 'Cart:{}',
  fields: {
    bookings(existingBookingRefs = [], { toReference }) {
      return [...existingBookingRefs, toReference(booking)]
    }
  }
});
```